# jQuery focus() on textarea that belongs to a form dynamicaly added into the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus, textarea

I am dynamically adding a new form into page using `clone()`, but when I add it I want to make form's textarea focused. I've got the code below but it doesn't work:

```
.on('click', '.edit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $comment_holder = $($(this).closest('li'));
            var $edit_form = $('.comments form').clone();
            $edit_form.find('textarea').focus();
            $comment_holder.append($edit_form);
 });
```

I found many related questions here on SO, but they didn't help solve my issue.

Comment: You aren't appending cloned FORM to the DOM, are you?!

Comment: Write the focus statement after you append it to the dom.

Comment: So ya, focus it once it is appended, not before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using jQuery's `appendTo` just after you've cloned it

```
$edit_form.appendTo( $comment_holder );
```

In other words;

```
.on('click', '.edit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $comment_holder = $(this).closest('li');
    var $edit_form = $('.comments form').clone();
    $edit_form.appendTo( $comment_holder ).find('textarea').focus();
});
```